# scikit-learn random forest never finishes training, freeze

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, random-forest

i am trying to fit a random forest model with scikit-learn on ubuntu 14.04.-server machine. My data is of shape (150000, 270) the `verbose=10` output looks as the following:

> building tree 1 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    6.1s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 2 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:   12.2s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 3 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:   18.3s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 4 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:   24.9s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 5 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:   32.1s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 6 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   6 out of   6 | elapsed:   38.5s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 7 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   7 out of   7 | elapsed:   45.3s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 8 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   8 out of   8 | elapsed:   52.0s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 9 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:   58.5s remaining:    0.0s
>   building tree 10 of 10
>   [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:  1.1min finished

After this it hangs/freezes for hours. I tried to vary both the `n_jobs` and `n_estimators` parameter in order to get the model less complex/prevent threading issues with `n_jobs`. This did not help.

My model looks like this:
`RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1234, n_jobs=1, n_estimators=10, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, verbose=10)`

I read a lot about BLAS/MKL Threading issues and tried to set environment variables

`os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'`

`os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'`

`os.environ['NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'`

`os.environ['JOBLIB_START_METHOD'] = 'forkserver'`

But none of them helps. The model won't finish training. 
My script looks similar to this structure:

```
import packages/libraries

## load data 
## define model
## fit model
## predict on new data
```

Does anyone has experienced the same / something different?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Just a suggestion: maybe a helpful diagnosis would be to run your code on a smaller sample size first, say 15000 or 1500 examples.

Comment: the size of the data does not help. i already tried different sizes, smaller and bigger...

Comment: it seems that there is a kind of threading issue that causes any lock or something.... i tried without setting any enviornment variables and `n_jobs=-1`, and it does work fine, but uses all cores available... how can i restrict the number of cores used?  simply setting `n_jobs=4`or any other integer does not do anything but let the script just use one core.

Comment: Try adding `import multiprocessing;
multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver');` at the top of your code, before running or importing anything.. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: Sadly this does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a memory issue.

I suggest analysing how much memory the program uses when running.

Maybe trying running it with 10 samples from your dataset and see if it runs to completion.

Comment: in htop i am using up 10GB of RAM which equals to 5% of total memory.... I don't think this is a memory issue, as the ressources of the server-machine i have access to are quite huge...